# U2 Album songs still not leaving

Tags: iphone

I went to https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/offerOptOut to remove the album but it still won't go away! I signed in with my apple ID and when i hit "sign in" it just prompts me to sign in again straight after. It also did prompt me to sign in on my phone 4 but that also didn't do anything. when will it go away??

Comment: Try clearing cookies for Apple.com or opening up a Chrome Incognito (or similar) window to confirm it isn't a problem with cookies.